# My web scraper on the pirate bay does not return the torrents, what may be?

Tags: python, web-scraping

My web scraper on the pirate bay, does not return the torrents, what may be?

```
import requests
import lxml.html as html
import os
import datetime
import time

def thepiratebay(book):
    PB_MIRRORS = f'https://pirateproxy.surf/search.php?q={book}&all=on&search=Pirate+Search&page=0&orderby='
    LINKS_PATH = '//span[@class="list-item item-name item-title"]/a/@href'
    try:
        response = requests.get(PB_MIRRORS)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            home = response.content.decode('utf-8')
            parsed = html.fromstring(home)
            torrents = parsed.xpath(LINKS_PATH)
            complete_torrent = 'https://pirateproxy.surf'
            links_torrents = []
            for t in torrents:
                links_torrents.append(complete_torrent + t)
            print(f'THE PIRATE BAY: found {len(links_torrents)} torrents')
            return links_torrents
        else:
            raise ValueError('Error the mirror link doesnt work any more:  \n Change it in tbt.py ')
    except ValueError as ve:
        print(f'Error: {ve}')
```

The code does not return any torrent, it maybe the xpath but in chrome it detects the links. The path is:

```
 //span[@class="list-item item-name item-title"]/a/@href
```

Console results with the book small island:\

```
What book are you looking for?: small island
THE PIRATE BAY: found 0 torrents
```

Comment: `links_torrents.append(complete_torrent + torrents)` should be `links_torrents.append(complete_torrent + t)`

Comment: yes, i change it but the problem is that the torrents list is empty

Comment: what exactly does your code output? Also your `PB_MIRRORS` is not a [fstring](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/), yet you try to use formatting in there (`{book}`) - so that's just a bad link altogether as well.

Comment: I fix the fstring error, but continues giving a result of 0 torrents

Comment: Please update your code accordingly, and post the results from your terminal

Comment: okay, i do it..

Comment: have you tried any books with no spaces in their name?

Comment: yes, it continues without working. I think that is a a problem with the xpath, what cant identify it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the result comes from this API :

```
GET https://pirateproxy.surf/api?url=/q.php?q={book}&cat=
```

All links looks like this `/description.php?id=28037371` and the API above gives you the ids. So you can use something like the following :

```
import requests

search = "book"

r = requests.get("https://pirateproxy.surf/api",
    params = {
        "url": f"/q.php?q={search}&cat="
    })

links = [ 
    f'https://pirateproxy.surf/description.php?id={t["id"]}' 
    for t in r.json()
]
print(links)
```